# How to reconfigure BIOS of old PC from my laptop?

Tags: motherboard, bios

An unknown issue occured to my old dusty desktop while I was powering it up.

I saw no video on the VGA output, so I tried to reset the bios settings by removing the CMOS, that doesn't helpt, so I want to reconfigure the BIOS externally, is there a way to reconfigure a motherboard with another PC? The PC is old,  dating from 2007, but still has lots of potential with it's 4 GB of RAM and a dual core 3.0 GHZ processor, so I would like to utilise it.

Comment: What you want is not possible with that hardware you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact model of your motherboard this information is slightly vague but accurate none the less.

Check user guide (Can be obtained from manufacturer website) and see options for BIOS recovery. Sometimes motherboard allow you to flash BIOS pre-post in the event that BIOS somehow was corrupted. User guide will know for sure. If this is not possible you are better off trying to source an identical motherboard from ebay or manufacturer or getting a quote for replacement from a repair boutique (There are windows licensing issues when swapping out motherboards... can't just put in a different one, system will not login)

Long story short, no you cannot flash/program a BIOS using another PC.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Actually it is possible to control another PC's BIOS from another computer.  The hardware just has to support it.  ROG ASUS motherboards are known for this support.

Comment: packard bell iStart from 2007, all models seem to have the same mobo I think